# WP - Developing Locally, cant navigate to pages (trying to go up 1 director for index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am by no means a WP expert, although I am good at PHP (Dont like using these constricting frameworks).

I am revamping the theme of the blog I obtained, and I am doing some custom coding and styling etc. I made a local copy of the site http://localhost/site/ to develop with until I am comfortable uploading it live. Also, I created a local DB so I could set the url etc of the local site.

The main page loads http://localhost/site/ but when i try to navigate to a page in the site for instance http://localhost/site/about-us it says index.php cannot be found. I noticed when i put an index.php file in the http://localhost/ directory, for some reason it tries to load that page.

I have edited the .htaccess to have a rewritebase of /site/ but it still does not work.

Any suggestions? Something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Depending on the /wordpress folder location, you might need to configure your index.php file: please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
- Check on General Settings your "WordPress address" and "Site address" fields, should have your local environment's values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server is ignoring htaccess or you don't have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?